# Как можно запустить одну джобу в Gitlab CI/CD не затрагивая другие

Tags: gitlab-ci

Есть вот такой простой конфиг
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

job:renovate запускается только по шедулеру

job:testing-all (здесь может быть и какой-то сложный конфиг, а может целый пайплан с несколькими стадиями) запускается на каждый чих

При запуске шедулера у меня естественно выполняется `renovate` а потом все остальное
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути, при запуске `renovate` весь остальной пайп мне не нужен.

Как можно выделить сделать так, чтобы по шедулеру выполнялся только `renovate` и все?

Answer (score 1):

Придётся для всех других задач прописать правильный `only:`, ну или на крайний случай

```
  except:
     refs:
       - schedules
```

Можно слегка упростить себе задачу через наследование

```
.non-scheduled-job:
  except:
     refs:
       - schedules

testing-all:
  extends: .non-scheduled-job
  ...
```

Comment: Хороший вариант. Решили эту проблему с помощью тоже шаблона и `rules`